# All tags that start with

Tags: html, css, frontend

Is there any way to to specify styling for all tags that start with some prefix?

For example:

```
tst-* {
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
}
```

`<tst-some-tag>Some content</tst-some-tag>`

---

The reason why I want such selector is because I'm using Angular and have lots of custom components. All of them should be displayed as `block`. It could be very comfortable to specify `display` property for all custom elements ones, instead of adding class every time, when I use them.

Comment: Each `HTML` tag is for some specific reason. If you wants to apply same styles to different tags, use `class` and style with it.

Comment: You can't select parts of one tagname. You must to add something like class or a custom `data-*` attribute, and apply the solution in the answer of @to7be

Answer (score 4):

If you want to select elements **by class-name** you could do this: `[class^='class']`

If you want to select elements **by id** simply do this:
`[id^='id']`

In both cases you select all elements witch **start** with the text you put between the single quotation marks, either by class-name or by id.

Variations are also possible:
`div[class^='class']` or `div[id^='id']`

Answer (score 0):

You can add another class to those elements in Angular which would have the same css

```
<tst-some-tag class="tst-class">Some content</tst-some-tag>
```

You can simply add class to Angular just like jQuery way

```
var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( 'tst-some-tag' ) );
myEl.addClass('tst-class');
```

Comment: This is not an option, since `querySelector` method uses CSS selectors, so you still cannot use `tst-*` construction. 
I don't understand how `angular.element( document.querySelector( 'tst-some-tag' ) )` can help, if I still have to specify all tags that must have specific styling. Which means, I'll have to write: `angular.element( document.querySelector( 'tst-some-tag, tst-some-tag-2, tst-some-tag-3 ... tst-some-tag-N' ) )`

Answer (score 0):

According to all answers the best solution is to write specific class and add it on every custom element.

```
.tst {
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
}
```

`<tst-some-tag class="tst">Some content</tst-some-tag>`